# Reformate the date values of a csv dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

every one.

i have a csv dataset that look like this:

```
        'Date': ['1998-02-01 00:00:00', '02/18/2020 ', '1998-02-01 00:00:00', '03/17/2018']
```

What i want to do is to format all the date column into yyyy/mm/dd.

I tried this code:

```
data['Date'] = data['Date'].str.replace('-','/')
data['Date'] = data['Date'].str.replace(' ','/')
x = data["Date"].str.split("/")

if x.str[0] > "1900"
   data['Date'] = data['Date'].str[:10]

else:
   mm = data['Date'].str[:2]
   yyyy = data['Date'].str[-4:]
   dd = data["Date"].str.split("/")
   data['Date'] = yyyy+"/"+mm+"/"+dd.str[1]

data['Date']
```

but I keep getting errors, the most recurrent is "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas.to_datetime seems to be able to parse your datetime strings.

You can then use dt.strftime to format your datetimes.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1998-02-01 00:00:00', '02/18/2020 ', '1998-02-01 00:00:00', '03/17/2018']})
parsed = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
reformatted = parsed.dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
print(reformatted)
```